# Set up Redis for duplicate identification

Tags: redis, duplicates

I would like to use a Redis instance in order to identify duplicate records.

Any record can be identified by two features, the first feature is a hash of a string. The second feature is an array of hashes. So a new record is considered to be a duplicate if there is a match for its string hash or if any element in the array of hashes exists in another array of other element.

Example:

Record 1: 
`Id: 1, feature 1: ABC, feature 2: [aa,bb,cc]`

Record 2:
`Id 2, feature 1: ABC, feature 2: []` `--->` duplicate with record 1

Record 3:
`Id 3, feature 1: DDA, feature 2: [ff,bd,aa]` `-->` duplicate with record 1 (match on `aa`)

I am wondering how i can use Redis in its most efficient manner to be able to perform such operations.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build an index mapping from feature to record id, for each feature.

> The First Index

**Hash string to record id**. All keys of this index has a key prefix: *fea1:*

```
set fea1:ABC 1
```

> The Second Index

**Element of the hash array to record id**. All keys of this index has a key prefix: *fea2:*

```
set fea2:aa 1
set fea2:bb 1
set fea2:cc 1
```

> Duplicate identification

1. Build a key with the first feature, i.e. hash string, and search the first index:

   `exists fea1:ABC
   exists fea1:DDA`
2. If it doesn't exist in the first index, build keys with the second features, and search the second index:

   `exists fea2:ff
   exists fea2:bd
   exists fea2:aa`

**EDIT**

Since Redis 3.0.3, the `exists` command can check the existence of multiple keys. So you can do search the second index with only 1 redis command call:

```
exists fea2:ff fea2:bd fea2:aa
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. I am a bit worried about the complexity here, what if i have large numbers in the second feature array, i then need to call the `exists` N times

Comment: @AhmadAssaf Don't worry about that. Since Redis 3.0.3, `exists` can check the existence of multiple keys, and you only need to call it once. If you are using an older version, you can use pipeline to reduce TTL. You can also wrap the whole work into a lua script, only calls `eval` or `evalsha` once.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use **Sets** for this - see http://redis.io/commands/sadd

for the first feature start by `SADD feature1 ABC` , SADD will return the number of elements that were added to the set, not including all the elements already present into the set

so if the value is smaller then the number of values you tried to add then you have a duplicate.

do the same for the second feature 
`SADD feature2 aa bb cc`